# Redirect from non-www to www permanently

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, redirect

I am trying to redirect a domain from non-www to www

There are two ways I can do this ie on webserver level and using htaccess. If it is webserver then I have to do the redirect in two places one for port 80 and one for port 443?

Which one would be a good idea?

I am using nginx.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably not `.htaccess` as that is an Apache file and does not work with Nginx.

Comment: I also think so. I have done the www redirection on nginx and working ok but still would be interested to know the difference between doing this using htaccess or in nginx.